# IE form input element not being dynamically added to Window object per HTML5 specs

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dom

According to the HTML specs (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object), the window object is supposed to dynamically contain the elements from the page that are "named".  In my case, an input element that has an id attribute associated with it should exist on the Window object.

However, according to the HTML below (which passes HTML5 validation), IE doesn't recognize an input element by it's id on the window object if it's underneath a form element.

The following HTML will show an alert of "object" and then an alert of "undefined" in IE8 and IE10.  Why?  In FireFox and Google Chrome it shows both alerts of "object".  Is there something I'm missing?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HTML5 Standards mode</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="outerbutton" value="outer button">
        <form>
            <input type="button" id="innerbutton" value="inner button">
        </form>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(e)
            {
                alert(typeof outerbutton);
                alert(typeof innerbutton);
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`outerbutton` asnd `innerbutton` don't automatically become global JavaScript variables, just because you added some HTML that happens to contain an element with the same ID.

You need to use DOM methods to get to the element: `document.getElementById('outerbutton')`

Plus, your elements are **NOT NAMED**. You're using IDs.

If you had used:

```
<input type="button" name="pinky" id="outerbutton" value="outer button">
```

You'd be able to use

```
alert(document.forms[0].pinky.value);
```

...but this requires that the element be a member of the forms collection. So this will work on "innerbutton" not "outerbutton".

Comment: Actually, according to the HTML5 spec, all named elements are accessible via the window object.

Named objects are those that have child browsing contexts of the active document; a, applet, area, embed, form, frameset, img, or object elements that have a name content attribute; and HTML elements that have an id content attributee.

So, I should be able to access the inner input element by it's "name" which according to the specs is the id attribute on the window object.

Comment: The key here is "child browsing context of...form" which seems to mean that the input must be a child of FORM.

Comment: Let me rephrase my comment above.  
  
According to the HTML5 spec:  
Named objects with the name *name* are those that are either:  
1. child browsing contexts of the active document whose name is *name*,  
2. a, applet, area, embed, form, frameset, img, or object elements that have a name content attribute whose value is *name*, or  
3. HTML elements that have an id content attribute whose value is *name*.

Comment: Hmmm. interesting. So if the document is named, we should be able to get to the named inputs. I tried a few things in JSFiddle, but couldn't get any to work.